# What does args := []interface{}{} mean in golang?

Tags: go

It looks like it can be used as a list that can be filled with any types, but I don't understand the syntax. Why are there two set of {}?

```
    args := []interface{}{}

    args = append(args, check.ID, checkNumber)

    err := db.Exec(query, args...).Error
```

Comment: `[]type{}` is a slice composite literal; `interface{}` is the type (the empty interface with 0 methods); so `[]interface{}{}` is a slice composite literal where the slice's element type is `interface{}`. All types implement the empty interface (all types have these 0 methods), so any value can be assigned to a variable of `interface{}` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's build this up from the inner syntax to the outer syntax. Follow the links in my description for a detailed explanation of each syntax element.

- `interface{}` is a type specification for an [interface](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Interface_types) with no methods. This is commonly called the empty interface. All types satisfy the empty interface.
- `[]interface{}` is a [slice](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) of the empty interface.
- `[]interface{}{}` is a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) expression for a slice of empty interface containing no elements.

The first set of `{}` is part of the interface declaration. There are no methods in the interface.

The second set of `{}` is part of the composite literal expression for the slice. There are no elements in the slice.

As a side note, the code in the question can be reduced to:

```
args := interface{}{check.ID, checkNumber}
err := db.Exec(query, args...).Error
```

and further to:

```
err := db.Exec(query, check.ID, checkNumber).Error
```

The compiler automatically constructs the `[]interface{}` from [variadic arguments](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).